# How can you express radicals as multiplication/addition?

Tags: exponentiation, radicals

How can you express radicals as multiplication/addition?

Most mathematical operations clearly reduce to multiplication/addition (same thing), but how do you do that for exponentials/radicals? Thank you.

Example: $x^{1/2}$ = ?

Comment: You can't in general. If you have a particular expression you want help with please [edit] the question to include it, and tell us where it comes from and what you have tried.

Comment: This might be tangentially related: Suppose you want to relate 16^(3/4) to multiplication. Write 16 = (2)(2)(2)(2) and then 16^(3/4) equals the product of three-fourths of those factors: 16^(3/4) = (2)(2)(2) = 8.

Comment: The *reason* you can't in general is that addition and multiplication will always yield a rational number, but radicals can be irrational.

Comment: $x^{1/2} = t$ such that $t \cdot t= x$.

Comment: In high school and college in the late '60s (before calculators) we used to have to find square roots with paper and pencil. Here is one link to a [square root algoritm](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt668/emat6680.f99/challen/squareroot/sqrt.html) and there are many more such as this one for [cube root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^k; k\in \mathbb N$ is $\underbrace{x\cdot x\cdot .... \cdot x}_{k\text{ times}}$

With $x^0 = 1$ and $x^{-k} = \frac 1{x^k}$.

$x^{\frac 1k}$ the real number $y$ (if any... it is assume $x > 0$ and $y > 0$) so that $\underbrace{y\cdot y \cdot...\cdot y}_{k \text{ times}}= y^k = x$.

And $x^{\frac mk} = (x^{\frac 1k})^m$ or in other words if $y$ is the $y$ so that $\underbrace{y\cdot y \cdot...\cdot y}_{k \text{ times}}= x$ then $x^{\frac mk} = \underbrace{y\cdot y\cdot ...\cdot y}_{m \text{ times}}$.

Need to keep in mind:  1) The doesn't define $x^{v}$ where $v$ is not rational.  2) if $x < 0$ then ... this doesn't always work.  3) There are might be more than one $y$ so that $y^k =x$.  $x^{\frac 1k}$ refers specifically to the *positive* one, and 4) This makes a *lot* of assumptions that will need to be proven such as i) that such a $y$ so that $y\cdot ..... y=x$ actually exists; that there is exactly $1$ such thing and not many; ii) that if $\frac mk = \frac jl$ that $(x^{\frac 1k})^m = (x^{\frac 1l})^j$ etc.