# How to solve a root (eg, $x^{1/3}$) using arithmetic but without using a power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, arithmetic

How can I use the exponential constant and the natural logarithm operation, to express a "root" operation?

> Example: $x^{1/3}$.

Is there a combination of operations that are only arithmetic, using natural logarithm and/or the $e$ constant, which can express this without an exponential power operation?

The original expression (e.g. $x^{1/3}$) has only one variable, so the re-formulation should also only have the variable $x$.

> Example (incorrect): $x \cdot ln{3}$

I read the answers to [How can you express radicals as multiplication/addition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3182731/how-can-you-express-radicals-as-multiplication-addition) but didn't understand how it applies.

Comment: Are you allowing for infinite sums/products? Then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: $x^{\frac 13}=e^{\frac 13 \ln x} $

Comment: @lonestudent OP said without a power operation

Comment: @DanThousand thanks for the point. I didn't read well.

Comment: From the linked question, you would have $y\cdot y\cdot y=x$ in place of $y=x^\frac 13$.  Perhaps you can clarify a bit more on the intended results?

Answer (score 0):

you probably dont mean this,  but I'll write it anyway:

$x^{\frac{1}{3}} = e^{\frac{1}{3} ln(x)} $

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this still uses an power (exponent), so is not an answer to this question.